# For foreigners/tourists, if we rent a car in Singapore, do we need a valid Singaporean driving license?

Tags: legal, driving, driving-licenses, singapore

For foreigners/tourists, if we rent a car in Singapore, do we need a valid Singaporean driving license ?

As per my experience, I know some countries allow us to drive a car with our own country driving license for a certain amount of time, e.g. 1 month, more than that we are required to have local or international driving license.

Is it similar in Singapore ? or do we have different regulation here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Getting a Licence](https://www.police.gov.sg/resources/traffic-matters/getting-a-licence):

> Foreigners who reside here for less than twelve (12) months must possess a valid foreign licence and International Driving Permit (IDP) issued by an authorised body in their country of origin e.g. the Automobile Association (AA). If an International Driving Permit is not available, an official translation of your foreign licence in English is required.

Answer (score 2):

As a foreigner you can drive with your own license plus an International Driving Permit for up to twelve months before needing a local license. The IDP is actually a translation of your license and must be issued in the country which also issued your driving license.

[Source](https://www.ecitizen.gov.sg/Driving-in-Singapore-How-to-convert-a-foreign-driving-licence.html) - This also outlines the process for conversion after 12 months there.